# Update submodule in virtual environment with poetry

Tags: git, virtualenv, updates, git-submodules, python-poetry

How can I properly update the git submodule within poetry's virtual environment?
This is the project's folder structure:

```bash
main-project-repo/
├── .venv
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── submodule-package
│   │   │   ├── submodule_code.py
├── submodule-repo
│   ├── submodule-package
│   │   ├── submodule_code.py
├── main-project-package
│   ├── main_project_code.py
├── poetry.lock
├── poetry.toml
├── pyproject.toml
```

I've already make some changes to it and pushed at the submodule repository with:

```bash
$ cd submodule-path
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "update sub module code"
$ git push
```

and my main project repository.

```
$ cd .. # back to the root of main project repository folder main-project-repo
$ git add submodule-repo
$ git commit -m "feat: update submodule commit"
$ git push
```

This works fine to get the latest commit on submodule. But how can I properly update this within my virtual environment?

Here is how the submodule is defined in `pyproject.toml`:

```yaml
[tool.poetry]
name = ""
version = "0.0.1"
description = ""
authors = [""]
readme = "README.md"
packages = [
    {include = "submodule-package"},
]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = ">=3.9,<3.11"
...
submodule = {path = "./submodule-repo/", develop = false}
```

I don't want to reinstall all the virtual environment and install it again just because one package. There are a lot of other dependencies that I've omitted with `...` for simplicity

I've tried, with no success:

```bash
$ poetry update submodule
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (2.7s)

No dependencies to install or update

$ poetry update submodule-repo
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (3.0s)

No dependencies to install or update

$ poetry update submodule-package
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (2.5s)

No dependencies to install or update
```

Any ideas or suggestions?